# Parent and child divs both position: absolute. How to make child div take up 100% width and height of page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to make a light box style Jquery function. Unfortunately, the `.container` div that contains the image div (`.lightboxbackground`) I want to make pop out and enlarge has `position:absolute` and `z-index: 10` so my pop up box and background fader only take up the width and height of that parent (`.container`) div eg:

Would anyone know a way around this so that my `.lightboxbackground` and `.lightbox` divs can cover the whole screen?

```
<div class='container'>

  <div class='lightboxbackground'>
    <div class='lightbox'>
      <img src='image.jpg'/>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

.container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:10;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}


.lightboxbackground {
    background-color:#000;
    opacity: 0.9;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 11;
}

.lightbox {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 12;
}
```

Comment: ok.. why should the container be limited to 200x200? Not saying that it shouldn't, just I don't see a reason in this example

Comment: What's `.container` for?

Comment: You could do `position: fixed; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; z-index: 20;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to cover the whole screen:

```
.lightboxbackground {
    background-color:#000;
    opacity: 0.9;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index: 11; //I would advise to change this to z-index:1000 (Note: .lightbox must also adjust to this)
}
```

fid: http://jsfiddle.net/uH4MF/1/

Comment: why not just make the container 100% width and height?

Comment: because it would eat up the parent only which is only 200x200 px

Comment: ...  i mean.. why limit the parent to 200x200?

Comment: nice one.. I was thinking it is not possible using just css. :)

Comment: @Mr_Green the main issue I have with this sample is that if there's any element above this it will show. It would be best to use this trick with something like `z-index: 1000` :)

Answer (score 0):

`.container` is their "frame of reference", so to speak. 100% width and height of the descendants of `.container` means 200px for them.

Also, there *is* a way to attain 100% height. One of them is to to explicitly define `height` on `html` and `body` so you can have this reference.

And so:

- Place `.container` as a child of `body`

  ```
  <body>
    <div class="container">...
  ```
- Remove `.container`'s `width` and `height`
- Add the following style:

  ```
  html, body, .container {height:100%};
  ```

Comment: If there is no special reason to have 3 layers.. why not just combine .container and .lightboxbackground?

Comment: @user1600124 ask that to the OP. I'm just answering based on the provided code.